# Using a pipe character as a delimiter, but getting an invalid escape sequence error on it?

Tags: java, filereader

I'm not certain why I'm getting an "invalid escape sequence" error for using "\|", since it's supposed to make it just a | character? I'm attempting to read in a file, where values are separated by a | character, and for some reason it's giving me a very odd output. I have a text file:

```
Star Trek|Sci-fi|Sy-fy|48|is
Word Girl|Children's|PBS Kids|21|is
Firefly|Sci-fi|FOX|50|is
America's Next Top Model|Drama|CNN|51|is not
Being Human|Sci-fi|Sy-fy|48|is not
Black Mirror|Anthology|Channel 4|55|is
Grandma's House|Comedy|BBC Two|26|is
Sherlock|Crime drama|BBC One|55|is
Psych|Comedy-Drama|ION|51|is not
The Big Bang Theory|Sitcom|CBS|23|is not
```

I would like to go through this text file line by line, and then pass it through a TV shows class, which is as follows:

```
public class TVShows {

    private String showName;
    private String genre;
    private String network; 
    private String favourite;
    private String runningTime;

    public TVShows(String showName, String genre, String network, String favourite, String runningTime){
        this.genre = genre;
        this.showName = showName;
        this.network = network;
        this.runningTime = runningTime;
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return showName + ", on " + network + ", a " + genre + " show with a running time of " + runningTime + " minutes. This " 
                + favourite + " a favourite.";
    }


}
```

It's all very simple, but for some reason, when I implement it in the driver, which is here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File myFile = new File("./src/TVShows.txt");

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(myFile);

        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            TVShows myShows = new TVShows("test","test","test","test","test");
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(fileScanner.nextLine());
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter("\|");
            while(lineScanner.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(lineScanner.next());
                String showName = lineScanner.next();
                String genre = lineScanner.next();
                String network = lineScanner.next();
                String runningTime = lineScanner.next();
                String favourite = lineScanner.next();
                TVShows myShows1 = new TVShows(showName, genre, network, favourite, runningTime);


                System.out.println(myShows1);




            }

        }
    }
}
```

I get an invalid escape sequence error on "\|". Why is this? Do I just need to put another backslash in? Like "\|"? When I do this, and run the program, I get the output:

```
ÿþS t a r  T r e k
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Program3.Driver.main(Driver.java:30)
```

This is line 30:

```
String favourite = lineScanner.next();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, I ran it with two backslashes - it doesn't show up in "Do I just need to put another backslash in? Like "\|"?" For some reason, but I meant like " \ \ | ", and when I run it like that, it gives me the error that I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

you should use two backslash in java

```
lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two backslashes:

```
lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

First one is to escape the second one from parsing in the compiler. They together make a single backslash in the string constant that is used to escape the pipe symbol in the regex engine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea why I would still get an error after running it with two backslashes?

Comment: @Sarah, I'm not totally sure as I'm on a mobile device right now and cannot run your code. It is likely an issue where there are no more elements to get when you call next().

Comment: @Sarah, I'm also on a mobile device but @hexafraction would have right. You used `nextLine()` and `next()` into the both of out print.

Comment: @Sarah Your issue is that when you call `println(next())` you are pulling an additional element from the scanner. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This section of code

```
while(lineScanner.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(lineScanner.next());
            String showName = lineScanner.next();
            String genre = lineScanner.next();
            String network = lineScanner.next();
            String runningTime = lineScanner.next();
            String favourite = lineScanner.next();
        }
```

involves checking `hasNext()` once, then running `next()` six times. Therefore, if you have a number of elements not divisible by six, you will inevitably have some `n<6` number of elements left, get `n` elements, then get an error on trying to get the `n+1`th element.

From your data, I assume you are supposed to have 5 elements, not 6. I'm guessing that your `println` is disrupting the flow by requesting an extra element. Delete it and add `System.out.println(showName);` somewhere after you define `showName`; this should fix your problem.